# Error: No run dates were found for the given dates and dag interval

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I'm trying to run airflow DAG with:

```
my_dag = DAG(dag_id='my_dag', schedule_interval=None, start_date=days_ago(10),)
my_dag.clear(start_date=days_ago(10))
my_dag.run()
```

The `DAG` didn't start and I'm getting message:

```
{backfill_job.py:789} INFO - No run dates were found for the given dates and dag interval.
```

What is missing ?

Comment: Why do you need to run after clean? Clear already tell the scheduler that it should pickup the tasks (assuming DagRun existed)

Answer (score 0):

give `schedule_interval` a very large num, like timedelta(days=10086).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).